# Sliding Drawer Animation

Tags: android, animation, opacity, slidingdrawer

I need to decrease the opacity of the background of the sliding drawer as and when the slider is opening and increase the opacity when closing.

Tried Changing the background when slider is open/closed SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener/SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener , its not what i'm looking for.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is your setting transparent background is not doing the trick?

Comment: @AliImran setting the transparent image is working fine, I'm looking for something where the transparency increases along with the height of the slider. That is , when the slider is open 25% the transparency should be 75% and so on .. when the slider is open completely, the transparency  should be 100% .

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example try this :

Fading color effect with `TransitionDrawable`

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.translate);
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) layout.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(5000);
```

This code gives you a fading effect like from yellow to white(original color).

**translate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
          <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_state" />
          <item android:drawable="@drawable/original_state" />
   </transition>
```

**new_state.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFA7"/>
</shape>
```

**original_state.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```